# How to fix com.google.firebase.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Tags: java, android

The error is `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String`
I want to fetch the data in a recycler view but it gives me error.
I tried lot to fix the problem but i can't.
I give some code snippet

Firebase Model:

Data belong to my firebase database

```
     "user" : {
        "9gmWSVMhN4erdOeNCcXw7uB5Itq2" : {
          "email" : "look@gmail.com",
          "name" : "sagar",
          "password" : "asdfgh",
          "user_id" : "9gmWSVMhN4erdOeNCcXw7uB5Itq2"
        },

        "template" : {

          "FYKw520tCiPxrwi622xzdPzyGCi1" : {
            "-LbWzneRw0zTnE5naR2F" : {
              "c_address" : "aaa",
              "c_logo" : "https://www.freelogodesign.org/Content/img/logo-ex-7.png",
              "c_name" : "aaa",
              "p_designation" : "CTO",
              "p_email" : "yan@com",
              "p_name" : "name",
              "p_phone" : "012"
            },
            "-LbX2_P-KIaCEAkn9I3B" : {
              "c_address" : "bbb",
              "c_logo" : "https://www.freelogodesign.org/Content/img/logo-ex-7.png",
              "c_name" : "bbb",
              "p_designation" : "CEO",
              "p_email" : "gmail",
              "p_name" : "bbbb",
              "p_phone" : "098"
            }
     }
```

So i want to retrieve the the children under

I tried this code to retrieve data

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Accounts").child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", email + " / " + name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

This is my model class by which i received data
I think this class is good to get the data

Template.java

```
package com.example.look.np.models;

public class Template
{
  private String p_name;
  private String p_designation;
  private String p_email;
  private String p_phone;
  private String c_name;
  private String c_address;
  private String c_logo;
  private String tempID;

  //empty constructor
  public Template()
  {
  }
  //Constructor with variables
  public Template(String p_name, String p_designation, String p_email, String p_phone, String c_name, String c_address, String c_logo, String tempID)
  {
    this.p_name = p_name;
    this.p_designation = p_designation;
    this.p_email = p_email;
    this.p_phone = p_phone;
    this.c_name = c_name;
    this.c_address = c_address;
    this.c_logo = c_logo;
    this.tempID = tempID;
  }
  //Getter and Setter Methods 
  public String getP_name()
  {
    return p_name;
  }

  public void setP_name(String p_name)
  {
    this.p_name = p_name;
  }

  public String getP_designation()
  {
    return p_designation;
  }

  public void setP_designation(String p_designation)
  {
    this.p_designation = p_designation;
  }

  public String getP_email()
  {
    return p_email;
  }

  public void setP_email(String p_email)
  {
    this.p_email = p_email;
  }

  public String getP_phone()
  {
    return p_phone;
  }

  public void setP_phone(String p_phone)
  {
    this.p_phone = p_phone;
  }

  public String getC_name()
  {
    return c_name;
  }

  public void setC_name(String c_name)
  {
    this.c_name = c_name;
  }

  public String getC_address()
  {
    return c_address;
  }

  public void setC_address(String c_address)
  {
    this.c_address = c_address;
  }

  public String getC_logo()
  {
    return c_logo;
  }

  public void setC_logo(String c_logo)
  {
    this.c_logo = c_logo;
  }

  public String getTempID()
  {
    return tempID;
  }

  public void setTempID(String tempID)
  {
    this.tempID = tempID;
  }

}
```

This is my Fragment class where i want to show the data in the recycler view

MyCardFragment.class

```
public class MyCardFragment extends Fragment
{
  private static final String TAG = "MyCardFragment";

  RecyclerView templateRecycler;
  RecyclerviewAdapter adapter;

  List<Template> templateList;

  FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
  DatabaseReference databaseReference;
  DatabaseReference myref;
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
  FirebaseAuth auth;

  String key;

  //This is the empty constructor
  public MyCardFragment()
  {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  //This is the oncreate view where i wanna retrieve the data
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mycards, container, false);

    templateRecycler = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    templateRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("user").child("template").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

    return fragmentView;
  }
```

In the onstart method below i want to fetch data

```
  @Override
  public void onStart()
  {
    super.onStart();
    //Getting Template List From Database
    //The folloeing code block give me error
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
      {
        templateList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot templateSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {

          Template template = templateSnap.getValue(Template.class);
          //--->This line gives me error i don 't know what happed here
          //  -- > This line should give what i want
         // -- > I can 't understand whether the model class is incorrect or database refrence
          Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + template.toString());
          templateList.add(template);
        }
        adapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(getActivity(), templateList);
        templateRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
      {

      }
    });

  }
}
```

Note: By using this code data are retrieved once but I dont know what happen after then i was getting the error

Please help me out , it had been two days i want to fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny but it was IDE's fault.

I just updated IDE into recent version and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.According to your code for validating database reference add this statement

```
Log.i("Uid",firebaseUser.getUid());
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("user").child("template").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
```

After adding this line check logs whether the Uid is returing same key that is in your database or not.

2.If Key is matching then for checking the model class Try to print Logs

```
Log.i("template Snap key",templateSnap.child("c_address").getValue(String.class));
Template template = templateSnap.getValue(Template.class);
Log.i("template name",template.c_address);
```

After these two logs you will get know where exactly the problem is occuring and add these Logs here also So that I can understand where exactly the problem is occuring.
BTW Model class seems to be fine.

3.What is the parent of user?

4.Secondly Create the List<> object outside the OnDatachange Method.

Comment: Hello there, Info: i'm using navigation drawer where i have navigation drawer item named Mycard which refers MyCardFragment. When i click Mycard it gives me error which i mention at the top

Comment: after  Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + templateSnap.toString());



2019-04-16 22:32:31.139 28389-28389/com.example.look.np D/MyCardFragment: onDataChange: DataSnapshot { key = -LcaVMeriUCrfsg-rQOa, value = {tempID=-LcaVMeriUCrfsg-rQOa, p_email=yan@com, c_name=aaa, p_phone=012, p_name=name, c_address=aaa, c_logo=https://www.freelogodesign.org/Content/img/logo-ex-7.png, p_designation=CTO} }

Comment: The data that you have attached doesn't have tempID field but you get tempID in logs how this is possible and there are two childs in templatesnap but Log is giving only one child. Correct your logs or data in database.